# E-mail box for HTML website

Tags: html, email, html-email

So I have made myself a website. Since it has plans for being used I need someones help :)

I need users to fill in a few boxes and then send it to my email at thisismyemail@provider.com.

Since I am a little new I dont now how to do it.

The form: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hSi4.jpg
This is my code:

```
        <form action="../index.html" method="post" class="message">
            <input type="text" value="Naam" onFocus="this.select();"  onMouseOut="javascript:return false;"/>
            <input type="text" value="E-mail" onFocus="this.select();" onMouseOut="javascript:return false;"/>
            <input type="text" value="Onderwerp" onFocus="this.select();" onMouseOut="javascript:return false;"/>
            <textarea></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
        </form>
```

Now what I need is that it doesnt bring me to the index page but show a message with someone like: "Your message has been send" and that it sends it to my email, because at the moment it doesnt send it to anything.

Once more I am pretty new so please forgive my noobness :P

Thanks everyone,
Waylon194

Comment: with just html you can't achive this. You should use a server side language like php or java

Comment: You need php for this:
http://php.net/manual/function.mail.php

Comment: You can't send an email with client-side JavaScript alone, the server has to support an email protocol in order for emails to be sent

Comment: JavaScript is only for manipulating the DOM. To send mails you need server side code such as PHP.

Comment: You need a server-side script to send an email: JS can't do that for you. What JS can do is, however, send all the form information with AJAX to the server-side script, where the actual sending will take place, then return a success or error response back to the JS.

Comment: You have to write a php function using mail() and add it to your page.

Comment: Sure! You just need to learn how to pass the values from your form to that php function. If you give me a moment I'll explain it.

Comment: Someone already wrote an answer that could be helpful, check it ;)

Comment: How would people even know what your question is if you edit it out? If you have an answer or a suggestion, please post it as a comment or answer (if appropriate). Keep your question intact, so that future searchers may benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's a php html code that can be used to email, that you can start with.

**User inputs must always be sanitized accordingly. This code is just for demonstration.**

```
<?php
//if "email" variable is filled out, send email
  if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {

  //Email information
  $admin_email = "someone@example.com";
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
  $comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];

  //send email
  mail($admin_email, "$subject", $comment, "From:" . $email);

  //Email response
  echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
  }

  //if "email" variable is not filled out, display the form
  else  {
?>

 <form method="post">
  Email: <input name="email" type="text" /><br />
  Subject: <input name="subject" type="text" /><br />
  Message:<br />
  <textarea name="comment" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: how much do you know?

Comment: @Waylon194 — Writing a complete beginners guide to server side programing is far too broad a topic for Stackoverflow. I suggest you find an introductory tutorial.

Comment: ya agree with @Quentin but just letting him know that server side is needed to achieve this. just giving him an idea to start to know :)

Comment: my advice is learn a server side language(php), database(mysql) and client side languages(html,javascript) and styling(css) for web development :)

Comment: nope. my this code is the simplest of it that can be. your code is just html and its not enough. :)